# Key Tips in WPF

Tags: wpf

Office 2007 and the Ribbon introduced the concept of "[Key Tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/outlook/archive/2008/10/20/ribbon-key-tips.aspx)".

> In short, every single command in the
> Ribbon receives a letter which you can
> press to activate that command. ...
> The letters are indicated by small
> "KeyTips" which indicate the letter to
> press to activate the control. KeyTips
> are displayed using the Alt key, so
> using them feels similar to how menu
> navigation works in Windows.
>
> (Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/2006/04/12/574930.aspx)

An example of the Key Tips can be shown as follows. In this diagram, the use has pressed the ALT key, and is awaiting further input.

[Key Tips Example in Word 2007 http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/outlook/WindowsLiveWriter/RibbonKeyTips_8F7C/clip_image002_thumb.jpg](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/outlook/WindowsLiveWriter/RibbonKeyTips_8F7C/clip_image002_thumb.jpg)

**Are there any WPF Open Source examples of "Key Tips"?**

How would you go about implementing something like this feature in a generic way (i.e. not requiring a Ribbon)? How would you implement this using a MVVM pattern (given that ICommand does not support InputBindings).

Note: ActiPro have implemented this feature in their implementation of a [Ribbon](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/Ribbon/KeyTips.aspx), but they have not released source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could check out the [Ribbon Preview](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview) in the WPF Toolkit by Microsoft.

Or, one general approach would be like this:

1. Make a `DependencyProperty` in your Window / top-level control that you can trigger off of, like `IsShowingKeyTips`. Catch keyboard input to flip this as you deem appropriate.
2. Make a `ContentControl` that has two dependency properties like 1) `IsShowingKeyTip` and 2) `KeyTipText`. Let's call this `KeyTipContentControl`.
3. Edit the `ContentControl`'s `ControlTemplate` to look how you want. Make it a `Canvas` or your favorite layout container, use some bindings to size it properly, maybe throw in some negative `Margin` values.
4. If you want to be fancy, make some `AttachedProperties` like `KeyTip.Text` to bubble them up from the plain control to the `KeyTipContentControl`.
5. In your XAML, put the `ContentControls` around the `Controls` you want the KeyTips on. Set the bindings as appropriate.

You'll end up with something like this at the top level:

```
<Window ... >
  <code:KeyTipContentControl 
     KeyTipText="A" 
     IsShowingKeyTip="{Binding IsShowingKeyTips}">
     <Button x:Name="MyButtonWithKeyTip" ... />
  </code:KeyTipContentControl>
</Window>
```

To handle the key press in an elegant fashion is not something I'm up for right now. :-)

Comment: Hello @exclsr. I have a question that Key Tips must work in a hierarchical way that mean it can have multiple level of KeyTips. Can you help me a solution for resolve follow this approach ?

Comment: Hi @MR.LB, thanks for your question. I recommend opening a new Stack Overflow question. Good luck in your search.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Fluent Ribbon Control Suite](http://fluent.codeplex.com) (it's free & supports all required features)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Note that the question wasn't about which Ribbon to use, but in fact how to create KeyTips (specifically separate from any ribbon implementation). That said, this is an open source implementation of KeyTips, and for that reason, this is a useful answer.